# What species of Sempervivum is this?

Tags: identification, succulents, perennials

I have received these plants hardy to zone 6b, minimum temperatures of -23°C (-9.4°F). I know there are numerous species of Sempervivum that look alike, but I kind of hope somebody knows some details about them.
Their diameter is 2-9 cm (0.8-3.5 inches) and were collected from a garden with the approx. coordinates 46°N, 23°E, elevation 400 m (1300 ft).

The leaves are green. In reality the leaves don't have the white shine that appears in this photo.

[image]

Comment: Alina, thanks for putting the temperatures and measurements in a way that we all understand them, even the few of us who still use the Imperial system!

Comment: Actually I think it would have been nicer if I gave the Imperial units by default and the metrical in parentheses because the most part of the active users are from US. As far as I know, only Bamboo and Giacomo are in Europe, the rest of the potential answerers being imperial system users. I find metrical really convenient, that's why I use it by default, defying the statistics. :)

Comment: The white shine are probably the glandulose hairs. Flash beats portable lens, in some cases. If you were here (and it is a wild plant), I would say: http://www.sarkanperennataimisto.fi/kuvat/Sempervivum_wulfenii.htm

Comment: Thanks! It looks a lot like the plant in your link, the only difference being the white hairs at the edge of the leaves.

Comment: There are also so many hundreds of varieties and hybrids, and each looks different in different growth conditions. The closest answer will just be a guess based on pictures.